# Is "swiss army knife" a protected trademark?

Tags: trademark

I want to create the slogan for my library (in the programming, the [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) is distributable pre-made code for reuse) like "The Swiss army knife for type-safe TypeScript programmers"). But can I use the "Swiss army knife" so simply? Is it the trademark?

Comment: It's not infringment if the product has nothing to do with knifes. Also the swiss people are thousands of miles away from here.

Comment: @Cicero - not from here. 571 miles from where I sit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Swiss Army Knife" is indeed a trademark. Indeed, it is a very special trademark, because after the last of the Geneva Conventions was adopted, the use of the Swiss insignia used in the Swiss Army Knife's trademarked logo was prohibited except for grandfathered trademarks such as the one you identify.

But use of a trademark is infringing only when it is used in connection with the sale of a good or service to imply that the good or service sold is endorsed by or affiliated with the owner of the trademark. In the context you describe, the trademark is not being used in that fashion, and so it is not infringing.

Comment: "after the last of the Geneva Conventions was adopted, the use of the Swiss insignia used in the Swiss Army Knife's trademarked logo was prohibited except for grandfathered trademarks such as the one you identify": that's certainly not the case in Switzerland.  Pretty much every product of Swiss origin (which is a large proportion of the heavily protected Swiss market) has a Swiss flag.  But that's true even of US packages of Familia muesli, which Wikipedia tells me was introduced in the 1950's, so there must be something else going on with the Swiss insignia.

Answer (score 0):

There are many trademarks are related to the mark "Swiss Army Knife". An analysis shows the category & year distribution of thousands trademarks related to it. [image]

If you look deeper in this distribution, surprisingly the latest "Swiss Army Knife" trademark was applied on Dec 30, 2021, and it's still pending. [image]

I got this from [www.huski.ai](http://www.huski.ai), just FYI.

Comment: The name of the owner is misspelled.  I wonder who's responsible for that.